# Не удаётся загрузить текстуру из файла в SFML.Net

Tags: c#, sfml

Проблема в том что когда я пытаюсь загрузить текстуру из папки в SFML Net то мне выдаёт эту ошибку:

> SFML.LoadingFailedException: "Failed to load texture from file /Textures/square1.png"

На этой строке кода:

```cs
Texture square = new Texture("/Textures/square1.png");
```

Работаю в Visual Studio 2022 с версией C# 6.0. Буду рад если поможете.

P.s. папка проекта выглядит таким образом: [image: 1]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats

Comment: Что происходит, если используется обратный слэш `\` в пути к файлу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо указывать полный путь к текстуре
например:
Texture sprite = new Texture("F:/Projects/Tanks/Textures/tank.png");